# How to delete an folder thus name contains a control character?

Tags: linux, control-characters

## TL;DR:

A (kinda bad) python setup asked me for a path. I started typing,`backspace, backspace`, typed something other. Okay this setup created a folder with the following name (according to `ls`):

> ?[3~?[4~foo

Obviously the name contains some control characters. The parent directory contains some other very important folders that I can't move to execute a `rm -rf *`

Okay, so:

**How to delete the folder?**

I should mention I only have SSH access - there is no GUI.

`mv "?[3~?[4~foo" x` won't work obviously since these are control characters.

Comment: `ls -b` will show you the file name with the escape characters expanded. If `ls "?[3~?[4~foo"` shows only one file, then you can safely use `rm -rfi "?[3~?[4~foo"`. If it looks like it's OK try again without the `-i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wildcard matching - are there any important files in `ls *foo`? Also, you can try `ls *foo | xxd` to get the hex codes of the control characters.

Comment: facepalm, wildcards. I really dont know why I didn't had this idea myself. Thanks!